# I have problem with VS Code auto complete class names in html

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I have problem with VS Code auto complete classes names in html. When I add a class attribute to an element, it does not show the auto complete options for class names (value).
I have tried many extensions and also tried "editor.suggestions" in .json file, but none of them solved the problem.
So in html, when I want to use a class that I have already added I need to write it carefully so that it does not be wrong.
Could anyone help me with this problem, please?
By the way, I can access class name auto complete in css file. My problem is that in an html file, I do not access my class names (auto complete) which are defined previously in the html file.

Comment: write an extension that does what you want

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i needed only the classes auto-complete, so fixed the problem in the extension settings as below:

**/*.{css,html} to **/*.{css}

I removed the 'html'. And still autocomplete the classes.

Hope this helped you well as me.

[classes-names-autocompletion-issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTpv5.png)